# Rapid Test Driven Development in Java

Tags: java, junit, tdd, automated-tests

I have been using the [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) framework in rails for quiet a while and I have just fallen in love with it. I also work in Java a lot and I find it surprising that such a tool is not available for rapid test driven development. Here's what guard does for you (form the original website)-

> - File system changes handled by our awesome Listen gem.
> - Support for visual system notifications.
> - Huge (more than 120) guard extensions eco-system.
> - Tested against Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, REE and the latest versions of JRuby & Rubinius.

In essence, it helps me keep an eye on test cases while I am making changes or adding stuff to my codebase. The following are the benefits of such an approach-

- Unobtrusive test case driven development
- Instant acknowledgement of the impact of a code change
- High quality code
- Minimized regression ripples

Does anyone know how to achieve similar goals in Java?
Note- Automated test tools like Hudson is not an answer I am looking for. I need something that can be used on local development machines/environment so there is an instant test case feedback on a code change.

Thanks

Comment: Do you look for a tool that runs your java unit tests in the background all the time?

Comment: Yes. It should run all the time in the background.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you are looking for ... but if you search for a tool that runs your unit tests in the background during development have a look at [Infinitest](http://infinitest.github.com/) or [JUnit Max](http://junitmax.com/).

Comment: +1 for Infinitest, we have used it in my company. Just be careful, we found it really slowed down our machines in larger code bases. I guess just more reason to keeps things modular! :)

Comment: JUnit Max looks promising but it is paid. Infinitest has multiple issues- 1) It is very slow and runs all the test cases every time in eclipse. 2)Too few configuration options. 3) No project in the workspace can have build errors which is too much to ask. requirement.

Comment: JUnit Max is only for Eclipse too.

Answer (score 2):

If you work with eclipse, and you dock your JUnit view in a convenient place, it's ***one button*** to click to rerun your tests, and see the report immediately in the same view.

It's a very efficient way to perform test driven developpement.

Comment: Not really for the following reasons- 1) Not everybody uses Eclipse (for e.g. IntelliJ). 2) If I change a class, I would like to run the test cases which are affected by that class and not the whole suite. For e.g, we have some 600 test cases. I cannot run every test case manually on Eclipse and then proceed. 3) Eclipse is a memory hungry IDE which means running test cases and development on a large codebase is a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) with Hudson to do this for you. In the company I work in, we use this combination to solve your issue. There's also a Sonar plugin for Eclipse. But, if you look for something like an IDE-based solution I can't help you.